# strange behaviour of template_redirect in IE8

Tags: templates, actions

I have implemented page not found with a custom template and used `template_redirect` for it.

```
add_action("template_redirect", array($this, "redirection_section"), 11);
```

Now everything is working fine as expected but not in IE8, my redirect section method is here:

```
function redirection_section() {
        global $is_IE;

        if($is_IE) {
            echo "GOT IT!";
            exit;
        }
        if( is_404() ) {
            $this->uni_page_redirect();
        }
}
```

if i type like anything in the end of the url like `myurl.com/testing` its displaying me

> The webpage cannot be found

But if i call other menus or template or and templated related stuff then got the proper `GOT IT` message, But why not with `myurl.com/testing`? Can anyone tell me what is the reason or do i have to implement something else? Please guide me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I am updated the answer, so that it will be helpfull to others as well.

```
(For IE, IIRC it's 512 bytes)
```

#### Helpful links:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11121286/404-page-not-showing-up-in-ie9#answer-11133855
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970093/include-after-php-404-header-returning-oops-this-link-appears-to-be-broken